# Remember animation position across pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some divs in the page with animations and these divs are being reused across pages. How can I remember the position of the div when it is being navigated to another page and restore the position on the new page.

I tried getting and setting the jQuery .offset() but this did not restore the div position correctly.

```js
var elementClasses = [
    'baloon',
    'cloud-1',
    'cloud-2',
    'cloud-3',
    'sun-quote-page-wrapper'
];

function saveElementOffsets() {
    if (! parseInt($('#is-desktop').val())) {
        return false;
    }

    $.each(elementClasses, function (key, value) {
        var offset = $('.' + value).offset();

        if (! offset) {
            return true;
        }
        console.log(value, offset);
        localStorage.setItem(value, JSON.stringify(offset));
    });
}

function applyElementOffsets() {
    if (! parseInt($('#is-desktop').val())) {
        return false;
    }

    $.each(elementClasses, function (key, value) {
        var offset = localStorage.getItem(value);

        if (! offset) {
            return true;
        }
        console.log(value, JSON.parse(offset));
        $('.' + value).offset(JSON.parse(offset));
    });
}
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: from the code it looks like you are trying to store offset in localstorage by css class name of element but are those classes unique and applied to single element?

Comment: Yes, the class names are unique and applied to a single element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.offset()` to set the position, you need to use `.css()` to set the top and left css properties to get them in place.

The snippet doesn't function well because I can't use localStorage in it.

```js
var elementClasses = [
    'baloon',
    'cloud-1',
    'cloud-2',
    'cloud-3',
    'sun-quote-page-wrapper'
];

function saveElementOffsets() {
    if (! parseInt($('#is-desktop').val())) {
        return false;
    }

    $.each(elementClasses, function (key, value) {
        var offset = $('.' + value).offset();

        if (! offset) {
            return true;
        }
        console.log(value, offset);
        localStorage.setItem(value, JSON.stringify(offset));
    });
}

function applyElementOffsets() {
    if (! parseInt($('#is-desktop').val())) {
        return false;
    }

    $.each(elementClasses, function (key, value) {
        var offset = localStorage.getItem(value);

        if (! offset) {
            return true;
        }
        console.log(value, JSON.parse(offset));
        $('.' + value).css(JSON.parse(offset));
    });
}

function randomizePosition() {
  $.each(elementClasses, function (key, value) {
      $('.' + value).css({
        top: Math.random() * 500 + "px",
        left: Math.random() * 500 + "px"
      });
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="is-desktop" value="1" type="hidden" />
<div class="baloon"></div>
<div class="cloud-1"></div>
<div class="cloud-2"></div>
<div class="cloud-3"></div>
<div class="sun-quote-page-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @mylee I tried using .css() to set the offset object but the positions are not correct across pages.